# Color the border of image according to background color of div

Tags: html, css

[image: Border of image same as background of div]

Above is a image that i found at udacity. I think inside that there is a png image which is bg-less, and that image's border is colored the same as that of background of the div.

How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You make the image's border (black) opacity 50% (png needed for this) and the background color will shine through no matter what background color is used.

If the image is already fully transparent, with only a black border, you can use CSS and set `opacity: 0.5` to an element like this

```
img {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

div {
  background-image: url(...);
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would create a PNG image where the stroke of the illustration has a 50% opacity. Here's an example image:

[image]

And here's the same image with a colored background:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #00a573;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Il1Ur.png">
  </div>
```